# Error in placing and scaling elements in a flex

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

So I was trying to build a small website using HTML and SASS. I'm customizing a form input box as such shown in image [form input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1aTV.png) while its coming quite like this [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1pA0.png).

HTML

```html
<form action="input">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="off">
    <img id="error" src="/assets/images/icon-error.svg" alt="error.svg">
    <button type="submit">
        <img id="arrow" src="/assets/images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="">
    </button>
</form>
```

SASS:

```
form {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}
    
#email {
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border-color: $desaturatedRed;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    
    &::placeholder {
        color: $desaturatedRed;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    }
}
    
button {
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    background: $gradient2;
    border-radius: 50px;
    align-content: center;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -8%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
    
#error {
    margin-left: -10%;
    }
```

SASS VARIABLE.SASS:

```
$desaturatedRed: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
$softRed: hsl(0, 93%, 68%);
$darkGrayRed: hsl(0, 6%, 24%);
$gradient1: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 0%, 100%), hsl(0, 100%, 98%));
$gradient2: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please put all your code. It miss desaturated.

Comment: I have added the variables in the question. I thought it isn't much connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the svg-code ....

It seems you did not set the sizes to the image element with the svg at all.

Flexbox is not the helper to all positioning tasks. You can use bsolute positioning instead of flexbox in this case.

Maybe you like to tryout something like this in SASS:

```
form {
  //  --> use absolute positioning
  // display: flex;
  // align-items: center;
  position: relative;

  // --> size wrapper element for correct inner absolute positioning
  width: 70%;
}

#email {
  // inner element full width as wrapper element is sized
  width: 100%;
  // --> avoid unwhanted sizing effects using padding in input
  box-sizing: border-box;

  outline: none;
  background: none;
  border-color: $desaturatedRed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;

  &::placeholder {
    color: $desaturatedRed;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  }
}

button {
  // --> absolute positioning right
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background: $gradient2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-content: center;
  border-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  // margin-left: -8%; --> not needed as of absolute positioning
  // visibility: hidden; --> not seen when hidden ?!
}

#error {
  // --> absolute positioning from right with vertical centering
  position: absolute;
  right: 22%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;

  // --> sizing svg-image
  height: 35px;   // or similar
  width: 35px;    // or similar
}

#arrow {
  // --> sizing svg-image
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;   // depends on svg
}
```